# Finding the common words(intersection) in each row of 2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dHoVyEAi0SrY3QPgxRYXjl7CYkRvv0LVV_re38523ck/edit?usp=sharing

I wanted to compare the matching words(intersection) from `Dataframe1['Final_Text']` to the `Dataframe2['Text']`. Row 1 of `Dataframe2['Final_Text']` should compare with each row of `Dataframe1['Text']`, similarly row 2 `Dataframe2['Final_Text']` with each row of `Dataframe1['Text']` and show on.

Please suggest the possible ways.

Till Now, I have done for  a row

```
lexicon = set().union(*df2['Final_Text'].str.split())
```

Output-->

```
{'study', 'cell' , 'response', 'patient, 'effect','activity' 'cell,', 'protein,', 'result,'}
```

Dummy Data

```
data={'activity', 'cell','response','Study','Maths', 'DNA'}

c=data.intersection(lexicon)
print(c)
```

Final Output---> `'cell'`

Here instead of `data` I want to check with each rows of `Dataframe2['Text']`.

Comment: what is your code so far? what exactly do you want it to do, and what are your ideas and thoughts to this point how it could be achieved?

Comment: Please check, I have updated the body of the question.

Comment: Can you please suggest some possible option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over each row of a dataframe using `DataFrame.iterrows`: [see docs here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows). This will yield rows index and the contents of the row itself.
This allows you to do the following:

```
intersections = dict()
for index2, row2 in Dataframe2.iterrows():
    for index1, row1 in Dataframe1.iterrows():
        words1 = set(str(row1[1]).split())
        words2 = set(str(row2[1]).split())
        matching_words = list(words2.intersection(words1))
        rows = 'DF1:{} DF2:{}'.format(index1, index2)
        intersections[rows] = matching_words

print(intersections)

>> {'DF1:0 DF2:0': [], 'DF1:1 DF2:0': [… ...}
```

This will create a dictionary where strings containing the two row indices are keys and the according intersections are values, storing and organizing all your outputs for further use.

Comment: Thank you very much, on iteration, it gives an error. AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'intersection'

Comment: Right, `intersection` is an attribute of `set` objects. I'll edit my post right away

Comment: Thank you for your time, With the matching_words output is there but its blank, no matching word in any rows.

Comment: What do you get when printing `words1` and `words2`? can't try it out myself rn i'm on my phone

Comment: I am thankful for your time, I am getting the text of the rows from the both the dataframe. Only thing is that it is not able to take the intersection. I think the issue with this lien matching_words = set(words1.intersection(words2))

Comment: No error, output is like 'DF1:0 DF2:1': set(), 'DF1:0 DF2:2': set(), 'DF1:0 DF2:3': set(), 'DF1:0 DF2:4': set()     only there is no intersection. In data I have verified, there are intersections.

Comment: @Durgesh Nandini are all the words in `words1` and `words2` separate elements of the sets? what dors simply adding `print(words2.intersection(words1))` print?

Comment: No, sample output is like {0, 'cell patient study protein treatment result effect may gene expression'}
{339.0, 'The DNA complexation and condensation properties of two established cationic liposome formulations CDANDOPE 5050 mm Trojene and DCCholDOPE 6040 mm were investigated by using a combination of isothermal titration} They elements are not separated, this is the issue. Can you please suggest some function?

Comment: add an index to `row1` and `row2` when creating the sets like this: `words1=set(str (row1[1]).split ())` should be 1, but im not sure

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working perfecty. Now, I am calculating the number of  matching words using  y=len(matching_words) but instead of number of matching words its giving the position of the matched word. Can you please suggest some another alternative?

Comment: hm... thats weird... since `matching_words` is a list, and `len(list)` returns the number of elements in a list, this should be fine... what exactly do you mean by position? The word's position inside the list?

Comment: Yes, like. protein is the 3rd position so I am getting 3. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: would you consider your original question answered?

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot. I was trying hard.

Comment: what is the exact output of running `print(len(matching_words))`

Comment: You as well! and a happy new year :) when im home ill take a look at the rest of this stuff with the `len` function

Comment: If I iterate each one row at once of Datafrane 2 over the all rows of dataframe 1. I am getting 2 issue.for index2, row2 in df.iterrows(): is not able to read all word, it reading only 8 or 9 words. Can you suggest some possible way to store the matching_words into a list?

Comment: its possible that it takes the commas into some of the elements, you can work around that by using `split (',')`

Comment: Hello, Now, I got the issue, for index2, row2 in df6.iterrows(): for index1, row1 in df.iterrows(): The rows1 and rows2 are taking the size of minimum value. If row1 has 8 element then it will read only 8 elements of rows2 and vice versa

Comment: Hello, in the rows, I am getting _{'object', 'dtype:', 'Name:'}_ as a intersection. How to remove these words? @Flob